# node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,92): error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular-datatables

Full error:-

ERROR in node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,92): error TS1109: Expression expected.

dependencies:-

{
  "name": "default",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npm run tsformat",
    "tsformat": "tsfmt -r"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^9.0.1",
    "angular-user-idle": "^1.1.0",
    "braintree-web": "^3.50.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^3.0.0",
    "ng2-select2": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "ngx-braintree": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^11.1.9",
    "ngx-infinite-scroller": "^0.4.1",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.5.2-ng4",
    "primeng": "^4.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "summernote": "^0.8.11",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1", 
    "typescript-formatter": "^5.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.45",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.34",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose that you use angular-datatable@^9.0.1, which isn't compatible with your project dependencies.

Here the angular-datatable@^9.0.1 peer dependencies:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^9.0.6",
  "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.6",
  "@angular/core": "^9.0.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.6",
  "core-js": "^3.6.4",
  "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
  "jquery": ">=3.4.1"
}
```

So, I think you should at least downgrade angular-datatable package to make it compatible with angular 5, which you use.